Ag Grid: Rows collapsing to left on return to grid after initial render
I am using Ag Grid in React to display data with row groups.
All works well on initial render, however clicking away and returning to the grid causes a temporary visual 'glitch' in the grid, where all the rows are lumped to the left before expanding to their appropriate sizes again.
Verified that this had nothing to do with the resizing by removing all the resizing and the grid had no column resize events.
Anyone has any solutions for this?

I've encountered a similar issue in my own work. Despite my efforts, I haven't yet identified the root cause or found a definitive solution. The problem remains elusive, and I'm still exploring various approaches to resolve it.

The problem in my case was related to the rowStyle prop. Even when passing a static object to rowStyle, the React AG Grid component somehow triggered a re-render, causing the glitch you described. I resolved this memoizing the rowStyle value using useMemo and I passed this memoized value to the rowStyle prop.
